# Vagrant environment with multiple projects

Tags: git, vagrant

I want to be able to have a Vagrant environment that contains multiple projects. Those projects should be under version control, along with the Vagrant environment itself. Here's an example directory tree that I thought of:

```
MyProject
├── Environment/
│   ├── WSServer/ -> ../WSServer/
│   ├── Vagrantfile
│   └── Website/ -> ../Website/
├── WSServer/
└── Website/
```

("->" is a symlink)

One problem here is that VirtualBox doesn't like symlinks, and solutions online to fix this seem to be outdated in regards to VB v5. Even if there was a solution, if Environment/ was under version control, the symlinks again would be broken.

I had also thought that submodules would work, but again there's a few problems:

- Currently I am not working with a remote Git repository, but
- even if I was, it would be rather tedious and inefficient to have to commit and push every little change from either WSServer/ or Website/, and then pull from Environment/ just to see the changes.

So, how can I successfully keep the Vagrant environment, WSServer/, and Website/ all under version control and keep them in separate repositories? Or rather, what is the usual/standard way of going about this?

Answer (score 1):

I'd propose something that does not cover 100% the requirement but this is also what I am doing in some project and it works if you do not mind that Vagrantfile is not part of your git repo.

symlink does not work fine for vb as you noticed (it tries to find the target directory on the vm so generally it would not exist) so I have them for the host but I add a `synced_folder` on the `myproject/WSServer` directly and I have my git repo on this one directly. so all the work is done from this folder and I can commit/push from this folder and read from the vm directly using the synchronized folder.

*maybe coupling the above with git submodule could be working.*